# File backing store for Jazz RTC? Database or file based?

Tags: git, mercurial, clearcase, rtc, jazz

We currently use Clearcase for a large number of large projects. We use SQL Server as the file store in the background, and it has eventually reached a point where accessing files is just too slow.

Looking at GIT and Mercurial, we see a distributed VCS based on storing file differences - which has the potential to get much better local performance.

Does anybody know whether Jazz RTC has a file store backed by file differences or by a database? (The rumour mill is suggesting it is backed by DB2 :/ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you mean Jazz RTC, which has a [version control included](https://jazz.net/library/article/41/).

Its [Jazz RTC server](https://jazz.net/library/article/557/) supports DB2, Sql Server and Oracle.

[image]

However, a Jazz platform is very different from a DVCS like Git and Mercurial: it is an **application Hub** made to facilitate the communication between several software about the development lifecycle (requirements, versionning, changes, builds, ...).
The version control part is only a small portion of Jazz.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend on using Git for VCS and other systems for issue tracking, build servers, etc. The all-in-one solutions only go so far. Initially it may be easier to start, but you quickly run into the "weakest link in the chain".

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

File access with RTC/Jazz source control is fast.

On the Jazz SCM dev team (of which I'm a part), we have a large repo. It contains tens of thousands of files, and hundreds of thousands of file states. The load time (on our LAN) is limited by network speed: I can load 50k files (roughly 500megs) in 10 to 20 minutes. On a faster network, it would be better.

On the server, changes are kept as deltas (ie, differences between versions) where appropriate. The Jazz server is backed by a database, but access is quick.

Comment: Excellent: any system would be faster that our sloow ClearCase ;) I didn't find much documentation on the "distributed" aspect (new in RTC3.x) of the version control on Jazz server though.

Comment: If you have questions about distributed source control with RTC, ask on the [newsgroup](https://jazz.net/forums/viewforum.php?f=1).